# Ajax without data

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Im trying to display some data in a web page using Ajax, PHP and mysql, but I don`t know why this code is not functioning:

This is what I have in my js file:

```
function aprobar() {

var url = "../../php/Admin/aprobar_albumes.php";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: muestraContenido,
    error: funcionError
});

function muestraContenido(result, status, xhr) {
console.log('El resultado es: ' + result);
$("#datos").html(result);

function funcionError(xhr, status, error) {
alert('Error: ' + error + 'Status: ' + status);
```

My PHP file contains this:

```
// Nos conectamos a la base de datos
$link = mysqli_connect($cfgServer['host'], $cfgServer['user'], $cfgServer['password']) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($link));

// Seleccionamos la base de datos
mysqli_select_db($link, $cfgServer['dbname']) or die("Could not select database");

$query = "SELECT idAlbum, Nombre FROM PF_Album WHERE Publicado = 'N'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Query failed");

$i = 1;

while ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    if ($i == 1) {
        $template->loadTemplatefile("../../Templates/Admin/templateAprobar_album.html", true, true);
    }

    $template->setCurrentBlock("DATA");

    $template->setVariable("ID", $line['idAlbum']);
    $template->setVariable("ALBUM", $line['Nombre']);

     $template->parseCurrentBlock("DATA");

    $i++;
}

if ($i == 1) {
    $template->loadTemplatefile("./errorBusqueda.html", true, true);
    $template->setVariable("ETIQUETA", "");
} else {
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

@mysqli_close($link);
```

In my php file I just conect to my database and run a query.

But whenever I click the button the browser says: Error 404 (not found).

I`ve checked the paths of the files and they're fine

Comment: can you provide your directory structure?

Comment: The JS functions are missing the closing `}`. Is that in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: If you're getting 404 not found, it means you have the wrong URL for the PHP script. The error message should show the full URL.